# Matlab: How can i stop a the whole function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a function in matlab calculating something. Within that function I open another function to calculate something for it.
Now in this second function I have some case where I just want to stop everything if some certain condition is true (so I want to end both functions)

I don't want an error message or anything; Is there a command for that?

If I just type in `error` I get some notice in red with a message such as:

```
error: Invalid call to error.  Correct usage is:

 -- Built-in Function: error (TEMPLATE, ...)
 -- Built-in Function: error (ID, TEMPLATE, ...)

error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/help/print_usage.m at line 89, column 5
>>>error:   /home/john/wpq.m at line 75, column 4
error:   /home/john/test.m at line 23, column 21
```

if I write `error('blabla')` I still get:

```
>>>error: blabla
error: called from:
error:   /home/john/wpq.m at line 75, column 4
error:   /home/john/test.m at line 23, column 21
```

I would like to get no output because I can write one line above already something like `disp('the test on this number failed')`.

Comment: You can use a `return` statement, and return a value from the nested function to the main function. Then process the return value to halt the main function.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.. :) I guess it also works but if I'm inside the main function and I discover that the return value signifies that the function has been stopped - how do I stop the main function then without an error message?

Comment: But it only stops one loop.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing a try/catch block in your main function to expect the condition under which you want code execution to stop.
I don't believe that there is any one command that allows code to stop execution from a function within a function.

Comment: Thank you... I'm not familar with try/catch so I will read the manual for it... Thank you!! :)

Comment: One question: What do I write in the catch block if I don't want to have an error message to occur?

Comment: @J.Doe This article explains how try/catch works in Matlab: http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html
Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, I already read that - thank you... However I still don't know what to write in the catch block to terminate without an error message :(

Comment: Once you've caught the error in the catch block, you can write whatever you want in the catch block and then return from the function. E.g. you can put `disp('the test on this number failed')` in the catch block. It won't print an error unless you tell it to.

Comment: Ah, okay thats great... :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of doing what you want. Typically error is only meant to be used for things that actually is errors. You do for example get an "index out of bounds" error if you try to access an element outside the array. In case what happens is an error you should send an error message to inform users about what happens and highlight that this is an error. However, in case you only want this particular calculation to end and not the program I would instead recommend `try-catch` and printing the error message in `catch`.

In case this is normal termination (or if only a particular function terminates unnormally and this is expected for some input) you can either use a termination condition (`function [out,success] = myFun(in)`) or try-catch. Both are accepted, though I use to prefer the termination condition approach for normal termination and try-catch for unnormal termination (of functions). Unnormal termination can for example be when a function have to be terminated before all output variables are calculated. I use to prefer to have an exception thrown instead of a function returning invalid values (but a c-programmer would probably argue differently).

For the record, there is a `return`-statement in Matlab which terminates a particular function.

It is hard to recommend a particular approach without knowing the situation you are in, but this text would give you some different options to be choose between. Know that error handling seldom have standard approaches which can be said to be "right". It is often up to the programmer to decide what is suitable and that is typically a part of the design.

Good luck!